# AngularJS doubles request

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple controller

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp')
           .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, myService) {
              $scope.makeTodos = function () {
                   $scope.todos = [];
                   myService.getTodos().then(function (data) {                
                       $scope.todos = data.data;
                   });
              };

              $scope.makeTodos();
          });
}());
```

when I open the page, I see two requests (`myService.getTodos()`) Why ?

Comment: Just guessing here, but one of your requests is probably a pre-flight OPTIONS request, because your api is cross-domain. You can google for CORS to find out more about it

Comment: Can you 1) show the HTML structure, and 2) check the call stack for each `myService.getTodos()` call? And yes, I assume you're talking about several _calls_, not _requests_.

Answer (score 0):

I put the `ng-controller="myCtrl"` for two html elements on my page, that was the reason